Install older miktex versions
I had a MiKTeX installation(2.9) which was using a local package repository that I had from a long time ago. Now I had to reinstall the MiKTeX, but when I installed the new version of MiKTeX(24.1), I either had errors for pdf conversions or it would take way more time to convert. So I assumed that my old local package repo and the newer version of MiKTeX has some compatibility issues and I wanted to try MiKTeX 2.9.
Is there a way to find the installation file of MiKTeX 2.9.7140? On the MiKTeX installation website, there is only the latest version available to download, and for the MiKTeX Github repo, there is only the source code available for version 2.9.7140.

No, I don't think that older version exist, and even if you find one it will probably not be functional as it can't connect to the miktex repositories. Better spent your time on correcting your errors and documents.

@UlrikeFischer does it still have to connect to miktex repositories if I already have a local repository?

if you find a full version with all packages included perhaps not, but you won't be able to update anything and you won't get any support or help for it.
